# redux-persist not updating the state and persisting

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm trying to implement redux-persist, it shows the store with the initial values in the browser inspector but the values are never updated in the persist store

This is the localStorage shown in the browser, it never changes after I call the dispatch

```
userData
: 
"{\"userDetails\":{\"username\":\"\",\"name\":\"\"},\"status\":\"loggedout\"}"
_persist
: 
"{\"version\":1,\"rehydrated\":true}"
```

This is my store config
store.ts

```
import {
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  PreloadedState,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import { apiSlice } from './services/apiSlice';
import loginFormReducer from '../components/login/store/loginFormSlice';
import userDataReducer from './slices/userDataSlice';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
  whitelist: ['userData'],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginFormReducer,
  userData: userDataReducer,
  [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

//for testing purpose
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});

export function setupStore(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    preloadedState,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        },
      }).concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  });
}

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

this is the main where I set the persist gate
main.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import { setupStore } from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import './index.css';
import './mirage-mock-server/server';

let persistor = persistStore(setupStore());
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <Provider store={setupStore()}>
    <PersistGate
      loading={null}
      persistor={persistor}
    >
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```

The Slice where I call the initial data and the reducer where I change the state
userDataSlice.ts

```
import { UserData, UserDetails } from '../../types/UserDataType';

const initialState: UserData = {
  userDetails: {
    username: '',
    name: '',
  },
  status: 'loggedout',
};

export const userDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userData',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCredentials: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserDetails>) => {
      state.userDetails = action.payload;
      state.status = 'loggedin';
    },
  },
});

export const { setCredentials } = userDataSlice.actions;

export default userDataSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue here: [Having an issue with redux-persist not updating localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200761/having-an-issue-with-redux-persist-not-updating-localstorage/74200926#74200926)

I'd be curious to see if this change would fix the problem.

```
    setCredentials: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserDetails>) => {
      state.userDetails.username = action.payload.username;
      state.userDetails.name = action.payload.name;
      state.status = 'loggedin';
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working through a very similar situation and here is how I chose to solve it.

The crux of the issue is setting `preloadedState` in your main `configureStore` setup. As I understand it specifying `preloadedState` will override any persisted store data.  Refer to the docs https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/initializing-state. Specifically, where it says **"Without combineReducers() or similar manual code, preloadedState always wins over state = ... in the reducer"**

First, I would check to make sure you can indeed persist the store you want by removing `preloadedState` and returning the store object directly. Pass that store to your provider instead. See if that works.

If so then I would modify store.ts as seen below and keep in mind you import the correct store to your Provider:

```js
// Rest of file config and set up above here

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginFormReducer,
  userData: userDataReducer,
  [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

//for testing purpose
export function setupStore(preloadedState ? : PreloadedState < RootState > ) {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReduce,
    preloadedState,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  });
}

// Actual store used by the application 
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});



export type RootState = ReturnType < typeof store.getState > ;
export type AppStore = ReturnType < typeof setupStore > ;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Hope this helps!